# Matrix chain product

Tags: matrices

I’m Reading a book , and I’m stuck at a property of a product of matrix chain , it says that given

$$A_{i..k }=A_{i}\times A_{i+1}\times A_{i+2} \times  ...A_{k}$$ where every matrix is a $p_{i-1}\times p_{i}$ matrix ,the resultant matrix(whatever parenthesization you choose)  is a  $p_{i-1}\times p_{k}$ matrix. This is what I don't understand and it says that it is obvious but i really don't see why the resultant matrix has that form. I mean if you perform the operations from the left to the right it is easy to proof this property  but how can I prove it that this is true for any parenthesization ?

Comment: Try induction, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is *associative*. That means you can put the parentheses any way you like and it won't make a difference for the result. We usually take this as a given axiom.

Furthermore, the result of matrix multiplication has the number of rows of the leftmost argument and the number of columns of the rightmost argument.

Any other rows or columns get merged as part of matrix multiplication.

Comment: thanks for the reply , could you tell me please what is the name of  the property that says that the result of matrix multiplication has the number of rows of the leftmost argument and the number of columns of the rightmost argument? my book doesn't mention it

Comment: Here's a [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Properties_of_the_matrix_product_.28any_number.29) where these properties are listed. Alternatively, you can prove it by induction, starting from the property for 2 matrices.

Comment: @martin4567 This follows by induction from the definition of the matrix multiplication!

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove two basic properties: 1) A product of a $m \times k$ and $k \times n$ matrix is size $m \times n$, and if you multiply three matrices then you get the same formula for the entries of the product regardless of which two matrices you multiply first. This will establish your result by induction on the number of matrices in the product.